# Vue Test Utils: change window size

Tags: vue.js

How can I change the window size using [Vue Test Utils](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/) ?

Default window size is 1024x768

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```js
Object.assign(global.screen, {
  width: 800,
  height: 600
})

// if you only need one changed, the plain assignment syntax is shorter:
global.screen.width = 800;
```

---

If the above doesn't work, you should show us *exactly* where your code reads window size from.

If it reads from `innerWidth`/`innerHeight`, you can define them on the `window` object:

```js
[
  { prop: "innerWidth", value: 800 },
  { prop: "innerHeight", value: 600 }
].forEach(({ prop, value }) => {
  Object.defineProperty(window, prop, {
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    value
  })
})
```

If you're using media queries (matchMedia), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57180950/1891677) on how to mock it.

---

- Any of the above can be run inside the test(s) where you want the viewport size changed.
- Keep in mind it's not going to be reset back to defaults after you change it, so all following tests will be run on the last set dimensions, unless you revert them to defaults at the end of the test where you need them altered.